# How to identify particular row of the seat must be occupied in oracle query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have requirement like exit seats of flight each row at least one seat must be used(occupied).

For ex : Exit row seats are 4ABC,4DEF,5ABC,5DEF . in 4ABC at least one seat to be used and 4 DEF at least one seat should be used same for 5th row also. if 4ABC,4DEF,5ABC,5DEF each row at least one seat not used then need throw warning . I have query which return below results

```
SELECT FLIGHT_CARRIER,FLIGHT_NUMBER,SEAT_NUMBER,PAX_ID,LOCATION_ATT,flight_date,int_row_pos,availability_attribute
                FROM SEAT_ALLOC WHERE AIRLINE ='LL'
                AND FLIGHT_CARRIER = 'LL'
                AND LOCATION_ATT LIKE  '%E%'
                AND FLIGHT_NUMBER='7893'
                AND flight_date=to_date('2021-10-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Result

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygo2B.png)

now how can validate each row to check   availability_attribute is available.

I am planning to use HashMap to assign those values . But is there any query level we can handle like using case .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sample data as below:

```sql
WITH 
    seat_alloc (FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, SEAT_NUMBER, PAX_ID, LOCATION_ATT, INT_ROW_POS, FLIGHT_DATE, AVAILABILITY_ATTRIBUTE) AS 
        (   Select 'LL', 7893, '3D', Null, 'W-B', 3, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '3E', Null, 'B-M', 3, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '3F', Null, 'A-B', 3, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '4A', Null, 'E-M', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '4B', Null, 'W-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '4C', Null, 'A-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '4D', Null, 'A-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '4E', Null, 'E-M', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '4F', Null, 'W-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '5A', Null, 'W-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '5B', Null, 'E-M', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '5C', Null, 'A-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '5D', Null, 'A-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '5E', Null, 'E-M', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '5F', Null, 'W-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '6A', Null, 'W-B', 6, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '6B', Null, 'B-M', 6, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 7893, '6C', Null, 'A-B', 6, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual         
       ),
```

... create CTE with exit rows statuses:

```sql
    exit_rows_stat  AS
      (   Select    FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE, INT_ROW_POS, 
                    Case When SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1) IN('A', 'B', 'C') Then 'ABC' 
                         When SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1) IN('D', 'E', 'F') Then 'DEF'
                         When SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1) IN('H', 'J', 'K') Then 'HJK'
                    Else 'XXX' 
                    End "EXIT_BLOCK",
                    Count(*) "BLOCK_SEATS",
                    Count(Case When AVAILABILITY_ATTRIBUTE = 'Occupied' Then 1 End) "OCCUPIED_CNT"
          From      seat_alloc
          Group By  FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE, INT_ROW_POS,
                    Case When SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1) IN('A', 'B', 'C') Then 'ABC' 
                         When SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1) IN('D', 'E', 'F') Then 'DEF'
                         When SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1) IN('H', 'J', 'K') Then 'HJK'
                    Else 'XXX' 
                    End
          Having    Max(InStr(LOCATION_ATT, 'E')) > 0
      )
--  
--  FLIGHT_CARRIER FLIGHT_NUMBER FLIGHT_DA INT_ROW_POS EXIT_BLOCK BLOCK_SEATS OCCUPIED_CNT
--  -------------- ------------- --------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ------------
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23           4 DEF                  3            3
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23           4 ABC                  3            3
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23           5 DEF                  3            0
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23           5 ABC                  3            0
--
```

To fetch warnings join the above CTE with your data:

```sql
--  M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    s.FLIGHT_CARRIER, s.FLIGHT_NUMBER, s.FLIGHT_DATE, s.INT_ROW_POS, e.EXIT_BLOCK,
          Case  When  e.OCCUPIED_CNT = 0 
                Then  'ALERT *** Exit Row ' || s.INT_ROW_POS || ' Block ' || e.EXIT_BLOCK || ' all seats are empty!' 
          End "WARNING"
FROM      seat_alloc s
LEFT JOIN exit_rows_stat e ON(e.FLIGHT_CARRIER = s.FLIGHT_CARRIER And 
                              e.FLIGHT_NUMBER = s.FLIGHT_NUMBER And 
                              e.FLIGHT_DATE = s.FLIGHT_DATE And 
                              e.INT_ROW_POS = s.INT_ROW_POS)
GROUP BY  s.FLIGHT_CARRIER, s.FLIGHT_NUMBER, s.FLIGHT_DATE, s.INT_ROW_POS, e.EXIT_BLOCK,
          Case  When  e.OCCUPIED_CNT = 0 
                Then  'ALERT *** Exit Row ' || s.INT_ROW_POS || ' Block ' || e.EXIT_BLOCK || ' all seats are empty!' 
          End
ORDER BY  s.FLIGHT_CARRIER, s.FLIGHT_NUMBER, s.FLIGHT_DATE, s.INT_ROW_POS, e.EXIT_BLOCK
```

... the result should be ...

```sql
--  R e s u l t :
--  FLIGHT_CARRIER FLIGHT_NUMBER FLIGHT_DATE INT_ROW_POS EXIT_BLOCK WARNING                                                 
--  -------------- ------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- --------------------------------------------------------
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23             3                                                                    
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23             4 ABC                                                                
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23             4 DEF                                                                
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23             5 ABC        ALERT *** Exit Row 5 Block ABC all seats are empty!     
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23             5 DEF        ALERT *** Exit Row 5 Block DEF all seats are empty!     
--  LL                      7893 11-OCT-23             6
```

This should give you warnings for different carriers/flight numbers/planes/dates/... and resulting dataset could be processed further to get you what you need.

**UPDATE - Dynamic blocks of exit rows**  (after comments)
It looks like it is possible to get different blocks and seats of interest using just data provided. For this we will need a bit bigger sample dataset with three different seat settings.

```sql
WITH 
    seat_alloc (FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, SEAT_NUMBER, PAX_ID, LOCATION_ATT, INT_ROW_POS, FLIGHT_DATE, AVAILABILITY_ATTRIBUTE) AS 
        (   -- FLIGHT 1 - 6 seats - 2 blocks - abc + def - 2 exit rows 
            Select 'LL', 1111, '4A', Null, 'E-M', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '4B', Null, 'W-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '4C', Null, 'A-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '4D', Null, 'A-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '4E', Null, 'E-M', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '4F', Null, 'W-E', 4, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            
            Select 'LL', 1111, '5A', Null, 'W-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '5B', Null, 'E-M', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '5C', Null, 'A-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '5D', Null, 'A-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '5E', Null, 'E-M', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 1111, '5F', Null, 'W-E', 5, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            -- FLIGHT 2 - 8 seats - 3 blocks - ab + cdef + gh - 2 exit rows
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8A', Null, 'E-M', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8B', Null, 'W-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8C', Null, 'A-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8D', Null, 'A-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8E', Null, 'E-M', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8F', Null, 'W-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8G', Null, 'E-M', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '8H', Null, 'W-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9A', Null, 'W-E', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9B', Null, 'E-M', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9C', Null, 'A-E', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9D', Null, 'A-E', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9E', Null, 'E-M', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9F', Null, 'W-E', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9G', Null, 'E-M', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 2222, '9H', Null, 'W-E', 9, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            -- FLIGHT 3 -  7 seats - 3 blocks - ab + cde + fg - 3 exit rows
            Select 'LL', 3333, '8A', Null, 'E-M', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '8B', Null, 'W-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '8C', Null, 'A-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '8D', Null, 'A-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '8E', Null, 'E-M', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '8F', Null, 'W-E', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '8G', Null, 'E-M', 8, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            
            Select 'LL', 3333, '19A', Null, 'W-E', 19, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '19B', Null, 'E-M', 19, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '19C', Null, 'A-E', 19, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '19D', Null, 'A-E', 19, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '19E', Null, 'E-M', 19, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '19F', Null, 'W-E', 19, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '19G', Null, 'E-M', 19, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            
            Select 'LL', 3333, '29A', Null, 'W-E', 29, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '29B', Null, 'E-M', 29, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '29C', Null, 'A-E', 29, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '29D', Null, 'A-E', 29, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '29E', Null, 'E-M', 29, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '29F', Null, 'W-E', 29, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Occupied' From Dual Union All
            Select 'LL', 3333, '29G', Null, 'E-M', 29, To_Date('11.10.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'Available' From Dual 
        ),
```

Here we have three types of exit rows. First with 6 seats in the row that we wil split into 2 blocks with three seats each. Second flight has 8 seat row that will be split into 3 blocks wit 2-4-2 seats. The third flight has 7 seats exit rows to be split into three blocks with 2-3-2 seats. below is cte (exit_rows_stat) to do it:

```sql
    exit_rows_stat  AS
        (  Select Distinct FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE, INT_ROW_POS, 
                        LISTAGG(Case When InStr(LOCATION_ATT, 'E') > 0 Then INT_ROW_POS || SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1) End, '|') WITHIN GROUP (Order By SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1))
                            OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE, INT_ROW_POS) "SEATS",
                        Case When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 6 Then 3
                             When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 7 Then 2
                             When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 8 Then 2
                        End "BLOCK_1",
                        Case When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 6 Then 3
                             When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 7 Then 3
                             When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 8 Then 4
                        End "BLOCK_2",
                        Case When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 6 Then 0
                             When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 7 Then 2
                             When Count(Distinct SubStr(SEAT_NUMBER, -1)) OVER(Partition By FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE) = 8 Then 2
                        End "BLOCK_3"
              From      seat_alloc
        ),
```

```sql
/*
FL FLIGHT_NUMBER FLIGHT_DA INT_ROW_POS E SEATS                             BLOCK_1    BLOCK_2    BLOCK_3
-- ------------- --------- ----------- - ------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
LL          1111 11-OCT-23           4 Y 4A|4B|4C|4D|4E|4F                       3          3          0
LL          1111 11-OCT-23           5 Y 5A|5B|5C|5D|5E|5F                       3          3          0
LL          2222 11-OCT-23           8 Y 8A|8B|8C|8D|8E|8F|8G|8H                 2          4          2
LL          2222 11-OCT-23           9 Y 9A|9B|9C|9D|9E|9F|9G|9H                 2          4          2
LL          3333 11-OCT-23           8 Y 8A|8B|8C|8D|8E|8F|8G                    2          3          2
LL          3333 11-OCT-23          19 Y 19A|19B|19C|19D|19E|19F|19G             2          3          2
LL          3333 11-OCT-23          29 Y 29A|29B|29C|29D|29E|29F|29G             2          3          2 */
```

Next is another cte (exit_row_seat_blocks) to define the seats in blocks:

```sql
  exit_row_seat_blocks AS
    ( Select    FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE, INT_ROW_POS, 
                BLOCK_1, BLOCK_2, BLOCK_3, 
                '|' || SubStr(SEATS, 1, InStr(SEATS, '|', 1, BLOCK_1) - 1) || '|' "BLOCK_1_SEATS",
                '|' || Case When BLOCK_3 = 0 Then SubStr(SEATS, InStr(SEATS, '|', 1, BLOCK_1) + 1)
                       Else SubStr(SEATS, InStr(SEATS, '|', 1, BLOCK_1) + 1, InStr(SEATS, '|', 1, BLOCK_1 + BLOCK_2) - InStr(SEATS, '|', 1, BLOCK_1) - 1)
                       End || '|' "BLOCK_2_SEATS", 
                '|' || Case When BLOCK_3 != 0 Then SubStr(SEATS, InStr(SEATS, '|', 1, BLOCK_1 + BLOCK_2) + 1) End || '|' "BLOCK_3_SEATS"
      From      exit_rows_stat
      Order By  FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE, INT_ROW_POS
    )
```

```sql
/*
FL FLIGHT_NUMBER FLIGHT_DA INT_ROW_POS    BLOCK_1    BLOCK_2    BLOCK_3 BLOCK_1_SEATS            BLOCK_2_SEATS            BLOCK_3_SEATS           
-- ------------- --------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------ ------------------------ ------------------------
LL          1111 11-OCT-23           4          3          3          0 |4A|4B|4C|               |4D|4E|4F|               ||                      
LL          1111 11-OCT-23           5          3          3          0 |5A|5B|5C|               |5D|5E|5F|               ||                      
LL          2222 11-OCT-23           8          2          4          2 |8A|8B|                  |8C|8D|8E|8F|            |8G|8H|                 
LL          2222 11-OCT-23           9          2          4          2 |9A|9B|                  |9C|9D|9E|9F|            |9G|9H|                 
LL          3333 11-OCT-23           8          2          3          2 |8A|8B|                  |8C|8D|8E|               |8F|8G|                 
LL          3333 11-OCT-23          19          2          3          2 |19A|19B|                |19C|19D|19E|            |19F|19G|               
LL          3333 11-OCT-23          29          2          3          2 |29A|29B|                |29C|29D|29E|            |29F|29G|               */
```

With this we can build the strings of empty seats per blocks. If that list of empty seats per block is equal to block's seat list from above then show alert in warning column...

```sql
SELECT  FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, PAX_ID, INT_ROW_POS, FLIGHT_DATE, Max(WARNING) "WARNING"
FROM    ( Select  Distinct  a.FLIGHT_CARRIER, a.FLIGHT_NUMBER, a.SEAT_NUMBER, a.PAX_ID, a.LOCATION_ATT, a.INT_ROW_POS, a.FLIGHT_DATE, a.AVAILABILITY_ATTRIBUTE,
                CASE WHEN  InStr(b.BLOCK_3_SEATS, a.SEAT_NUMBER) > 0 And 
                    '|' || LISTAGG(Distinct Case When a.AVAILABILITY_ATTRIBUTE = 'Available' And InStr(b.BLOCK_3_SEATS, '|' || a.SEAT_NUMBER || '|') > 0 
                            Then a.SEAT_NUMBER End, '|') WITHIN GROUP (Order By a.SEAT_NUMBER) 
                              Over(Partition By a.FLIGHT_CARRIER, a.FLIGHT_NUMBER, a.FLIGHT_DATE, a.INT_ROW_POS) || '|' = Replace(b.BLOCK_3_SEATS, '||', '') 
                    THEN 'ALERT - Exit Row ' || a.INT_ROW_POS || ' all block 3 seats ' || b.BLOCK_3_SEATS || ' are empty!'
                    WHEN  InStr(b.BLOCK_2_SEATS, a.SEAT_NUMBER) > 0 And 
                    '|' || LISTAGG(Distinct Case When a.AVAILABILITY_ATTRIBUTE = 'Available' And InStr(b.BLOCK_2_SEATS, '|' || a.SEAT_NUMBER || '|') > 0 
                            Then a.SEAT_NUMBER End, '|') WITHIN GROUP (Order By a.SEAT_NUMBER) 
                              Over(Partition By a.FLIGHT_CARRIER, a.FLIGHT_NUMBER, a.FLIGHT_DATE, a.INT_ROW_POS) || '|' = BLOCK_2_SEATS
                    THEN 'ALERT - Exit Row ' || a.INT_ROW_POS || ' all block 2 seats ' || b.BLOCK_2_SEATS || ' are empty!'
                    WHEN  InStr(b.BLOCK_1_SEATS, a.SEAT_NUMBER) > 0 And 
                    '|' || LISTAGG(Distinct Case When a.AVAILABILITY_ATTRIBUTE = 'Available' And InStr(b.BLOCK_1_SEATS, '|' || a.SEAT_NUMBER || '|') > 0 
                            Then a.SEAT_NUMBER End, '|') WITHIN GROUP (Order By a.SEAT_NUMBER) 
                              Over(Partition By a.FLIGHT_CARRIER, a.FLIGHT_NUMBER, a.FLIGHT_DATE, a.INT_ROW_POS) || '|' = BLOCK_1_SEATS
                    THEN 'ALERT - Exit Row ' || a.INT_ROW_POS || ' all block 1 seats ' || b.BLOCK_1_SEATS || ' are empty!' 
                    END "WARNING"
          From      seat_alloc a 
          Left Join exit_row_seat_blocks b ON(b.FLIGHT_CARRIER = a.FLIGHT_CARRIER And
                                              b.FLIGHT_NUMBER = a.FLIGHT_NUMBER And
                                              b.FLIGHT_DATE = a.FLIGHT_DATE And
                                              b.INT_ROW_POS = a.INT_ROW_POS)
        )
GROUP BY   FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, PAX_ID, INT_ROW_POS, FLIGHT_DATE
ORDER BY   FLIGHT_CARRIER, FLIGHT_NUMBER, FLIGHT_DATE, INT_ROW_POS
```

```sql
/*
FL FLIGHT_NUMBER PAX_ID INT_ROW_POS FLIGHT_DA WARNING                                                         
-- ------------- ------ ----------- --------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
LL          1111                  4 11-OCT-23                                                                 
LL          1111                  5 11-OCT-23 ALERT - Exit Row 5 all block 1 seats |5A|5B|5C| are empty!      
LL          2222                  8 11-OCT-23                                                                 
LL          2222                  9 11-OCT-23 ALERT - Exit Row 9 all block 2 seats |9C|9D|9E|9F| are empty!   
LL          3333                  8 11-OCT-23                                                                 
LL          3333                 19 11-OCT-23 ALERT - Exit Row 19 all block 3 seats |19F|19G| are empty!      
LL          3333                 29 11-OCT-23 ALERT - Exit Row 29 all block 2 seats |29C|29D|29E| are empty!  */
```

Comment: Great. Thank you @d r. only change i have done in above query in place of left out join used Right outer join . 
Thank you for your Time & help .

Comment: hi @d r

How to make above query as dynamic . some flights Exit seats defined as 'ABC' and 'HJK' . In this case query will fail. I have tried  by changing query but unable to find. 
I have created new question . Please find below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77386456/unable-to-make-group-by-dynamically-in-oracle-database

Comment: @satish Just updated the answer. You can define your blocks in Case expression of the exit_rows_stat CTE. Change the both Case expressions - in Select List and in Group By clause. I don't know what you have in your data but this should help. The alternative is to have the blocks defined in a separate table and fetch them from that table.

Comment: @d r . Thanks . If we want to make dynamic . We need to define separate table and get the blocks from that table right ? we can't make dynamic by using same same query ?

Comment: @satish It is not dynamic as it is fixed per every plane so one option is to put all existing blocks, if possible, in the Case expression as in the updated answer above (multiple ... When this Than that ... ). The other option is to have a table with different blocks of seats addrressings per airliner/airplane joined to the query to fetch the block definitions from.

Comment: @satish Also, if by dynamic we consider different planes/carriers, When part of CASE can be with multiple conditions like - When (Carrier = 'RY' and SeatLetter In('A','B','C')) Or (Carrier = 'LH' and SeatLetter In('X','Y','Z')) Then 'SomeBlock' ..

Comment: @d r . It won't work out this case because. The exit seat configuration they are doing on each flight . It will be difficult to provide fixed value for each flight . there may be 100 flights and it should be generic. instead of providing ABC or DEF . I am not sure how we can handle .  it will be great if we achieve generic way . fixed value not approving for me
Thanks in advance

Comment: @satish the cte exit_rows_stat returns just blocks having E in LOCATION_ATT columns. I realy don't know your data but if those are seat letters and there are 3  of them per block then even if there could be exit anywhere letterwise there are just about 10 groups of letters before there are no more letters. If you put it in the Case with 10 WHEN - THEN definitions it should be enough. Block names are irrelevant - it could be ABC or DEF but also could be FRONT LEFT or BACK RIGHT. If you group it descriptive then you don't even need all of those 10 conditions in Case expression.

Comment: @satish will try to propose something else this afternoon...

Comment: @satish Just posted an UPDATE - Dynamic blocks of exit rows . There is the logic to create dynamyic seat setings in blocks generated just from your sample data.

Comment: Thanks dr . I will check this solution and let you know on this.

Comment: Thanks dr . 
If possible could you please combine and send. It will be useful to me . I am getting some exceptions .

Comment: @satish You can combine (copy-paste) two ctes plus the main SQL (the last one) just put keyword WITH at the beginnig. It is like WITH exit_rows_stat  AS ( code from exit_rows_stat  ),  exit_row_seat_blocks AS ( code from exit_row_seat_blocks ) here goes main SQL (last one starting with SELECT in capital letters). I could do it but to send where ???? Here we already have taken a lot of space.

Comment: @satish This solution gives you freedom to define more than 2 blocks per exit row in case of bigger airplanes with more than 6 seats in a row. In the update there are 3 combinations as an example of the logic because I don't know your actual data. Basically the code discoveres exit rows, groups seats of the row in blocks (2 or 3 and could be even more), and warns if eny block is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions and conditional aggregation to check that at least one seat is booked in each block of seats:

```
SELECT FLIGHT_NUMBER,
       SEAT_NUMBER,
       flight_date,
       availability_attribute,
       CASE
       WHEN COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN availability_attribute = 'Occupied' AND seat_number IN ('4A', '4B', '4C')
              THEN 1
              END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY flight_number, flight_date) > 0
       AND  COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN availability_attribute = 'Occupied' AND seat_number IN ('4D', '4E', '4F')
              THEN 1
              END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY flight_number, flight_date) > 0
       AND  COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN availability_attribute = 'Occupied' AND seat_number IN ('5A', '5B', '5C')
              THEN 1
              END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY flight_number, flight_date) > 0
       AND  COUNT(
              CASE
              WHEN availability_attribute = 'Occupied' AND seat_number IN ('5D', '5E', '5F')
              THEN 1
              END
            ) OVER (PARTITION BY flight_number, flight_date) > 0
       THEN 'Has exit seats occupied'
       ELSE 'Exit seat not occupied'
       END AS exit_check
FROM   SEAT_ALLOC;
```

Change the `PARTITION BY` clause if you need different groupings and include any additional columns and filters you need (they were removed as they appeared to be unnecessary to demonstrate the necessary technique).

Comment: Thanks your Answer . Actually each flight exit row seat may vary . Instead of hardcoding seat number in section. How to provide dynamically based on query results . If other flight exit rows are 5th row and 6th row . That time this condition won't work .can you pls help on here

Comment: @satish Store details of the exit seat groups in another table and then use a correlated sub-query to check if you have at least one seat booked in each group.

Comment: OK. With out creating a table is there any other apporch I cam try . Since new table creation my team not allowing. Thank you for your response

Comment: @satish You need to know where the exit seats are for a particular plane. Can you describe in simple English sentences the logic for how you would know for any given plane where the exit seats are? If the answer is that for airframe type X it is seats on these rows, for airframe type Y it is those seats and for Z it is another set of seats then that is naturally data that should be stored in a table. Asking how to solve it without a table is very difficult if you do not want to hard-code it into the query.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned earlier query I came to know by exit seat using LOCATION_ATT coulmn. If LOCATION_ATT LIKE  '%E%' in Seat_alloc table.  Table is there I thought you are asking to store other table . Please let me know if you need further details . Could you pls check my starting  query which i posted while asking question how i am retrieving seats

Comment: @satish If you do not hard-code the seat numbers (or provide some other way of knowing where the exit seats are) then I do not think it is possible to solve the problem without an additional table.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that a `LOCATION_ATT` value containing an 'E' (`LIKE '%E%'`) identifies the seat as being in an exit row. Also that we don't know which rows are the exist rows, and there may be 0 or more exit rows. I'm also working on the basis that all the aircraft in question have a single aisle with 3 seats either side (`ABC` and `DEF`).

Further, the airline, passenger and date values are superfluous to the question, so I've left those out.

Some sample data, including non-exit-row values:

```
WITH seat_alloc (seat_number, location_att, row_number, seat_avail) AS (
    SELECT '4A', 'E-M', 4, 'Occ' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '4B', 'W-E', 4, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '4C', 'A-E', 4, 'Occ' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '4D', 'A-E', 4, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '4E', 'E-M', 4, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '4F', 'W-E', 4, 'Occ' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5A', 'W-E', 5, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5B', 'E-M', 5, 'Occ' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5C', 'A-E', 5, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5D', 'A-E', 5, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5E', 'E-M', 5, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '5F', 'W-E', 5, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6A', 'W-B', 6, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6B', 'B-M', 6, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6C', 'A-B', 6, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6D', 'A-B', 6, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6E', 'B-M', 6, 'Vac' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6F', 'W-B', 6, 'Vac' FROM dual),
```

We can see that in row 5, none of the seats `D`, `E` or `F` have been filled, meaning that a warning should be produced. I've broken the problem into some smaller sections, produced here as CTEs. First, let's just get the exit row seats:

```
exit_seats AS (
    SELECT row_number,
           seat_number,
           seat_avail
    FROM   seat_alloc
    WHERE  location_att LIKE '%E%'),
```

And then work out how many are empty in each block:

```
exit_unoccupied_ABC AS (
    SELECT row_number,
           COUNT (*) seats_free
    FROM   exit_seats
    WHERE  UPPER (seat_avail) = 'VAC'
    AND    seat_number IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT row_number || 'A' FROM exit_seats UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT row_number || 'B' FROM exit_seats UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT row_number || 'C' FROM exit_seats)
    GROUP BY row_number),
exit_unoccupied_DEF AS (
    SELECT row_number,
           COUNT (*) seats_free
    FROM   exit_seats
    WHERE  UPPER (seat_avail) = 'VAC'
    AND    seat_number IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT row_number || 'D' FROM exit_seats UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT row_number || 'E' FROM exit_seats UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT row_number || 'F' FROM exit_seats)
    GROUP BY row_number)
```

From this it's easy to produce a warning as needed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT es.row_number,
       abc.seats_free AS ABC,
       def.seats_free AS DEF,
       'Warning: empty exit seat block' AS warning_text
FROM   exit_seats es
INNER JOIN exit_unoccupied_ABC abc on es.row_number = abc.row_number
INNER JOIN exit_unoccupied_DEF def on es.row_number = def.row_number
WHERE (abc.seats_free = 3 OR def.seats_free = 3)
```

Output:

```
ROW_NUMBER        ABC        DEF WARNING_TEXT
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------------------
         5          2          3 Warning: empty exit seat block
```

Comment: hi rgm565 Thanks for your Answer . Could you please combine all above queries and provide . Actually i have tried by clubbing all . I am facing Error report -
Unknown Command .
It will be great if you combine all and i will try to execute . 
Thanks,

Comment: Hi @satish, with the alternative provided by d-r, do you still want my complete query?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got it . I will let you know if any thing required.  Thank you

Comment: hi @rgm565 

How to make above query as dynamic . some flights Exit seats defined as 'ABC' and 'HJK' . In this case query will fail. I have tried  by changing query but unable to find. 
I have created new question . Please find below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77386456/unable-to-make-group-by-dynamically-in-oracle-database

Comment: Hi @satish, as I mentioned in my assumptions, this works based on a standard single-aisle aircraft with 3 seats either side. Comments and answers to your new question make it clear that the best solution is to have a table defining aircraft configuration, and I completely agree. If my answer has been helpful, please be so kind as to mark it as correct.

Comment: ok. Thank you .