# Unable to make group by dynamically in Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have requirement to identify the emergency exit seats in flight. I need to identify if any of the row/unit at least one seat should be occupied if not need to show warning message to user.
I got solution from below stack trace. But the problem is in the solution row hard coded like 'ABC' , 'DEF'.
But the problem is some flights row defined as 'ABC' , 'HJK'. how to make this dynamic . I tried but its not working

All the details and Answers i have mentioned in below stack trace. Sine its kind new question i have started

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77333543/how-to-identify-particular-row-of-the-seat-must-be-occupied-in-oracle-query)

Since all the requirement i have asked in above thread. i have not provided full details like test data and query.

Please let me know if you need more details. If required i will provide all test data again.

Comment: [Edit] your question and give a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; a detailed description of the logic you are using to identify the exit seats (i.e. for flight number `ABC`, a 16 seat inter-island aircraft, the logic would be ..., for flight number `DEF`, an 800 seat jet-liner, the logic would be ...); how you provide this "dynamic" information; and the expected output for that sample data. Do **NOT** try to clarify in comments as you cannot include sufficient detail/formatting (and the clarification should be part of the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the seat groups.

Convert the seat number to a row and column and then you can find the maximum column value for each row. As you have no way to specify the actual seat groups then if you make the assumption that seats will be either in a left or right seat group and the left seat group will be in columns in the lower-half of the seat columns, measured from the maximum column value, and the right seat group will be in the upper-half of the columns, again based on the maximum value, then you can use that to assign individual seats to the groups.

Given all that then you can aggregate and use a `HAVING` clause to filter seat groups that have no occupied seats:

```sql
SELECT flight_number,
       flight_date,
       seat_row || LISTAGG(SUBSTR(seat_number, -1))
                     WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY seat_column)
         AS unoccupied_exit_seats
FROM   (
  SELECT flight_number,
         flight_date,
         seat_number,
         availability_attribute,
         seat_row,
         seat_column,
         CASE
         WHEN seat_column * 2
              <= MAX(seat_column) OVER (
                   PARTITION BY flight_number, flight_date, seat_row
                 )
         THEN 'L'
         ELSE 'R'
         END AS seat_group
  FROM   (  
    SELECT flight_number,
           flight_date,
           seat_number,
           availability_attribute,
           SUBSTR(seat_number, 1, LENGTH(seat_number) - 1) AS seat_row,
           ASCII(SUBSTR(seat_number, -1)) - 64 AS seat_column
    FROM   seat_alloc
    WHERE  location_attributes LIKE '%E%'
  )
)
GROUP BY
       flight_number,
       flight_date,
       seat_row,
       seat_group
HAVING COUNT(CASE availability_attribute WHEN 'Occupied' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE seat_alloc (
  flight_number          VARCHAR2(10),
  seat_number            VARCHAR2(4),
  flight_date            DATE,
  availability_attribute VARCHAR2(10),
  location_attributes    VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO seat_alloc(
  flight_number,
  seat_number,
  flight_date,
  availability_attribute,
  location_attributes
)
SELECT 'FN',
       x || y,
       SYSDATE,
       CASE
       WHEN (x, y) IN (
              (1, 'C'),
              (4, 'B'),
              (8, 'A'), (8, 'B'), (8, 'C'), (8, 'D'), (8, 'E'), (8, 'F'),
              (12, 'D'), (12, 'E'), (12, 'F')
            )
       THEN 'Occupied'
       ELSE 'Unoccupied'
       END,
       CASE
       WHEN x IN (4, 8, 12) THEN 'E'
       ELSE NULL
       END
FROM   (SELECT LEVEL AS x FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12)
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT CHR(64 + LEVEL) AS y FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6);
```

Outputs:

| FLIGHT_NUMBER | FLIGHT_DATE | UNOCCUPIED_EXIT_SEATS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FN | 2023-10-30 13:00:43 | 4DEF |
| FN | 2023-10-30 13:00:43 | 12ABC |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/224a-JBb)

Comment: Thank you @MTO .  I have run query tested couple of scenarios its working . Could you please help me . If i want to verify for each row instead block . How can i change . 

Above you provided query for Block(ABC or DEF example) .

if i want to verify for Row (ABCDEF example). It will be very helpful provide this one. Actually i have two requirements Block and Row based on configuration 
Once again Thank you very much

Comment: @satish Find the seat row, don't worry about working out the group (i.e. you should be able to eliminate the middle sub-query) and then just use the same technique with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` without including the `seat_group` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Its worked . Thank you very much @MTO. Could you please let me know it should work for all the configurations right irrespective of the ABC or DEF or HJK or etc based on configuration . I have tested its working . Just wanted to check with you

Comment: @satish I have no idea what data you have so I cannot say. It will work if your data matches the assumptions listed in the text at the start of the answer... if your data does not match those assumptions then it may not work as expected because your data is different.

Comment: what ever you provided data its matching and working . If any thing required. i will provide details you with full data.

Comment: hi @MTO

The given solution query work seats are in left and right side . but in flight middle seats also chance of configure . This can case how can i handle. Pls suggest.

Comment: @SKK You should [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and provide a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for the sample data (as text not images); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; an English (not code) explanation of the logic that you want to implement; and the expected output for the sample data. (However, the real solution should be to create another table to store the exit seats).

Answer (score 0):

> how to make this dynamic?

You need to know where the exit seats are for each flight. This will either be data that is stored in another table or data that you are getting from an external source (and then you should be asking why it is not stored in a table). Don't try to dynamically pass the exit seats into the query every time you run the query; just store the information in a table because the airlines are unlikely to reconfigure the seating on their planes for every journey so you can just set a standard configuration for each aeroplane (or even each airframe model / carrier combination as they are likely to use standardised layouts).

---

Assuming that you have a table that lists all the seats for each particular flight (if not then create the table) then you can add a column stating whether a seat is part of a group of exit seats:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_listing_all_seats_per_flight (
  id NUMBER(10,0)
     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
     PRIMARY KEY,
  flight_number   VARCHAR2(8),
  seat_number     VARCHAR2(4) CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(seat_number, '\d{1,3}[A-Z]')),
  exit_seat_group VARCHAR2(10)
                  CHECK (exit_seat_group IS NULL
                        OR REGEXP_LIKE(exit_seat_group, '\d{1,3}[A-Z]{1,7}')),
  UNIQUE (flight_number, seat_number)
);
```

Then you can find the unallocated exit seats using:

```sql
SELECT flight_number,
       flight_date,
       LISTAGG(exit_seat_group, ', ')
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LPAD(exit_seat_group, 10, '0'))
         AS unoccupied_exit_seats
FROM   (
  SELECT s.flight_number,
         s.flight_date,
         a.exit_seat_group
  FROM   table_listing_all_seats_per_flight a
         LEFT OUTER JOIN seat_alloc s
         PARTITION BY (s.flight_number, s.flight_date)
         ON (s.flight_number = a.flight_number AND s.seat_number = a.seat_number)
  WHERE  a.exit_seat_group IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY
         s.flight_number,
         s.flight_date,
         a.exit_seat_group
  HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN s.availability_attribute = 'Occupied' THEN 1 END) = 0
)
GROUP BY
       flight_number,
       flight_date;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE seat_alloc (
  flight_number,
  seat_number,
  flight_date DATE,
  availability_attribute VARCHAR2(10),
  CONSTRAINT seat_alloc__fn_sn__fk FOREIGN KEY (flight_number, seat_number)
    REFERENCES table_listing_all_seats_per_flight (flight_number, seat_number)
);

INSERT INTO table_listing_all_seats_per_flight (flight_number, seat_number, exit_seat_group)
SELECT 'FN',
       X || Y,
       CASE
       WHEN x IN (4, 8, 12) AND y <= 'C' THEN x || 'ABC'
       WHEN x IN (4, 8, 12) AND y >  'C' THEN x || 'DEF'
       ELSE NULL
       END
FROM   (SELECT LEVEL AS x FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12)
       CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT CHR(64 + LEVEL) AS y FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6);

INSERT INTO seat_alloc(flight_number, seat_number, flight_date, availability_attribute)
SELECT flight_number,
       seat_number,
       SYSDATE,
       'Occupied'
FROM   table_listing_all_seats_per_flight
WHERE  flight_number = 'FN'
AND    seat_number IN (
         '1A',
          '4B',
          '5C', '5D',
          '8A', '8B', '8C', '8D', '8E', '8F',
          '12F'
        );
```

Outputs:

| FLIGHT_NUMBER | FLIGHT_DATE | UNOCCUPIED_EXIT_SEATS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FN | 2023-10-30 10:11:59 | 4DEF, 12ABC |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7BZ68Evl)

Comment: @MTO Thanks for you Answer. All the Available seat i am getting from seat_alloc table. Do i need to create a column in this table. If yes . My team won't allow to create column. Because the impact will be very huge. Is there any solution like without creating column it will be great help

Comment: @satish As stated in the answer, you should probably have a table that defines which seats are exit seats either for each aeroplane or for each airframe model/carrier pairing because the exit seats are unlikely to change between the flight an aeroplane takes this week and the flight it takes next week/month/year. Then you do **NOT** need to change your `seat_alloc` table and you can achieve what you want using a `JOIN` to this new table.

Comment: By using location attribute we are identifying exit seats in seat_alloc table there is no separate table actually . 
by using column in table LOCATION_ATTRIBUTES LIKE  '%E%' we are checking .

Comment: @satish Your question does not define a [MRE] and neither does the question that you link and although it mentions `LOCATION_ATTRIBUTES LIKE '%E%'` it **NEVER** explains what that means or why it is relevant. I have serious doubts that it is possible to achieve what you want using the `LOCATION_ATTRIBUTES` column because, based on your previous questions, you appear to want to consider multiple groups of exit seats and you, again, **NEVER** define the logic of how to identify those groups of seats. Tell us (in English) what your table means and how to implement the logic.